# Liferay with Struts , JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts, liferay

I have web application developed using JSP and struts. I am just looking out for options to have different look and feel , and Ajax rendering . Liferay was suggested by one of my team mate. But I am not able to get much details on it. How do i make it work with the current product. ?

Liferay is portlet and is different from my existing product on servlet based. How can I integrate them. Is it possible to get liferay's portlet in place without much problem.

Thanks in advance, 
Priya.R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be able to make this with these two tutorials:

a) http://vegdave.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/building-a-helloworld-portlet-with-liferay/

Basic tutorial for Liferay installation on Tomcat, on the last line there is a reference to Glasfish server. Also the comments after the blog writing may help.

b) http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/struts-2-portlet-tutorial.html

I suppose you're using Struts2 nowadays. So, there is a way to make a Struts2 project to a Portlet according to this info.

Helpful?